# strange gulp-uglify minifier 'file.isNull()' error on gulp build

Tags: reactjs, gulp, minify, gulp-uglify

I'm building a relatively simple project in learning React w/Flux. I'm using (or attempting to use) Gulp to create an automated build with Browserify, Reactify, Streamify, and Uglify, all installed via npm. The whole flow was working, I made a few file changes, rebuilt, and now it is kicking out on error when I run the build. Even after reverting the changes and returning back to the original, previously working state. I'm suspect that perhaps a permission change has occurred somewhere, but I haven't done that myself, so I'm not sure how to diagnose that further (and not certain if the problem is there).

I should add that at first I suspected a vinyl streaming error was the problem, but I added the `.pipe(buffer())` and `vinyl-buffer` into the build flow, however it did not change the error.

Here's gulp:

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var uglify = require('gulp-uglify');
var htmlreplace = require('gulp-html-replace');
var source = require('vinyl-source-stream');
var buffer = require('vinyl-buffer');
var browserify = require('browserify');
var watchify = require('watchify');
var reactify = require('reactify');
var streamify = require('gulp-streamify');
var gutil = require('gulp-util');

var path = {
    HTML: 'app/index.html',
    MINIFIED_OUT: 'build.min.js',
    OUT: 'build.js',
    DEST: 'dist',
    DEST_BUILD: 'dist/build',
    DEST_SRC: 'dist/src',
    ENTRY_POINT: './app/App.js'
};

gulp.task('build', function(){
    browserify({
        entries: [path.ENTRY_POINT],
        transform: [reactify]
    })
        .bundle()
        .pipe(uglify().on('error', gutil.log))
        .pipe(source(path.MINIFIED_OUT))
        .pipe(buffer())
        .pipe(streamify(uglify(path.MINIFIED_OUT)))
        .pipe(gulp.dest(path.DEST_BUILD));
});

gulp.task('replaceHTML', function(){
    gulp.src(path.HTML)
        .pipe(htmlreplace({
            'js': 'build/' + path.MINIFIED_OUT
        }))
        .pipe(gulp.dest(path.DEST));
});

gulp.task('production', ['replaceHTML', 'build']);
```

Here is the error:

```
[09:54:33] Using gulpfile /Library/WebServer/Documents/lldb/gulpfile.js
[09:54:33] Starting 'replaceHTML'...
[09:54:33] Finished 'replaceHTML' after 8.3 ms
[09:54:33] Starting 'build'...
[09:54:33] Finished 'build' after 27 ms
[09:54:33] Starting 'production'...
[09:54:33] Finished 'production' after 7.07 μs
/Library/WebServer/Documents/lldb/node_modules/gulp-uglify/minifier.js:67
    if (file.isNull()) {
             ^

TypeError: file.isNull is not a function
    at DestroyableTransform.minify [as _transform] (/Library/WebServer    /Documents/lldb/node_modules/gulp-uglify/minifier.js:67:14)
    at DestroyableTransform.Transform._read (/Library/WebServer/Documents/lldb/node_modules/gulp-uglify/node_modules/through2/node_modules/readable-stream/lib/_stream_transform.js:172:10)
    at DestroyableTransform.Transform._write (/Library/WebServer/Documents/lldb/node_modules/gulp-uglify/node_modules/through2/node_modules/readable-stream/lib/_stream_transform.js:160:12)
    at doWrite (/Library/WebServer/Documents/lldb/node_modules/gulp-uglify/node_modules/through2/node_modules/readable-stream/lib/_stream_writable.js:326:12)
    at writeOrBuffer (/Library/WebServer/Documents/lldb/node_modules/gulp-uglify/node_modules/through2/node_modules/readable-stream/lib/_stream_writable.js:312:5)
    at DestroyableTransform.Writable.write (/Library/WebServer/Documents/lldb/node_modules/gulp-uglify/node_modules/through2/node_modules/readable-stream/lib/_stream_writable.js:239:11)
    at Readable.ondata (/Library/WebServer/Documents/lldb/node_modules/browserify/node_modules/read-only-stream/node_modules/readable-stream/lib/_stream_readable.js:572:20)
    at emitOne (events.js:77:13)
    at Readable.emit (events.js:169:7)
    at readableAddChunk (/Library/WebServer/Documents/lldb/node_modules/browserify/node_modules/read-only-stream/node_modules/readable-stream/lib/_stream_readable.js:195:16)
```

Welcome any ideas - thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Notice the removal of the extra parentheses - (). This returns these to the references they should be, not the functions the js is trying to call. How the extra () got written into isNull and isStream between when my code was running and when it stopped running is anyone's guess (and a little concerning) - I did not make those changes.

They are references, yes, but references to functions exported in modules. `require('./lib/isNull')` returns the export of that module; the export is a function, so `isNull` is a function. By removing the parentheses, you now only check whether `file.isNull` is anything which would be always true.

But, you are looking at the wrong things anyway. That’s not where `file` comes from. [`file`](https://github.com/terinjokes/gulp-uglify/blob/557b4d2e09c897961a84476a798f34f36d41f3ac/minifier.js#L64) is being passed as a parameter to the `minify` function. So `file` is an object that is supposed to have `isNull` and `isStream` methods.

The `minify` function is being called with [`through2`](https://github.com/terinjokes/gulp-uglify/blob/557b4d2e09c897961a84476a798f34f36d41f3ac/minifier.js#L100), so if your gulp file fails then that likely means that you did something wrong, probably with the order. Unfortunately, the error messages are not really helpful most of the time.

When looking at your gulpfile, I notice that you have two calls to `uglify`:

```
.pipe(uglify().on('error', gutil.log))
…
.pipe(streamify(uglify(path.MINIFIED_OUT)))
```

The first one looks fine and is what `gulp-uglify` usually looks like. But the second seems more like you tried to use the raw `uglify` (not `gulp-uglify`) there. That doesn’t seem like a good idea and since `uglify` is referencing `gulp-uglify`, it won’t work anyway. So better remove that line.

I’d also suggest you to look at the [official recommendation](https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp/blob/master/docs/recipes/browserify-uglify-sourcemap.md) on how to use browserify with uglify and fix the order of your `uglify()` call: You should call it *after* `buffer()`.

```
browserify(…)
    .bundle()
    .pipe(source(path.MINIFIED_OUT))
    .pipe(buffer())
    .pipe(uglify())
    .on('error', gutil.log)
    .pipe(gulp.dest(path.DEST_BUILD));
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so this was weird - I'll post for anyone to comment and/or update.

Following the error path, I opened the `minifier.js` file under `gulp-uglify`. Line 67 (ref. error above) showed this:

```
if (file.isNull()) {
      return callback(null, file);
    }

    if (file.isStream()) {
      return callback(createError(file, 'Streaming not supported'));
    }
```

Problem is that isNull and isStream are not functions - they're references. So the code needs to be changed to:

```
if (file.isNull) {
      return callback(null, file);
    }

    if (file.isStream) {
      return callback(createError(file, 'Streaming not supported'));
    }
```

Notice the removal of the extra parentheses - `()`. This returns these to the references they should be, not the functions the js is trying to call. How the extra `()` got written into isNull and isStream between when my code was running and when it stopped running is anyone's guess (and a little concerning) - I did not make those changes.

For anyone interested, the full path explanation is below.

---

The references for isNull and isStream are made in index.js here:

```js
module.exports = {
  ...
  isStream: require('./lib/isStream'),
  isBuffer: require('./lib/isBuffer'),
  isNull: require('./lib/isNull'),
  ...
};
```

Which refers to this function under `gulp-uglify -> node_modules -> gulp-util -> lib -> isNull.js (& isStream.js)`, which look like this:

```js
module.exports = function(v) {
  return v === null;
};
```

So - remove the function calling brackets `()` in minifier.js makes the correct reference and the gulp build runs without error.

Looks like a `gulp-uglify` issue at the end of the day (I'm guessing).

Comment: I'm just amazed that there's a discrete module for testing equality with `null`